# Access Variables Created During onMount in Svelte

Tags: javascript, svelte, svelte-3

I'm working my first Svelte app which includes an embedded Google Map.

[Setup Google Maps With Svelte 3](https://fireship.io/snippets/setup-google-maps-with-svelte/) provided a good starting point for creating a component which asynchronously loads a Google Map. However, I can't figure out how to access the `map` object outside the initial `onMount` call, and without access to that object I can't add in functionality I want (for example, re-centering the map based on a button the user clicks).

`main.js`

```js
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
    props: {
        ready: false,
    }
});

window.initMap = function ready() {
    app.$set({ ready: true });
}

export default app;
```

`App.svelte`

```html
<script>
    import Map from './Map.svelte';
    export let ready;
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <script defer async src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={}&callback=initMap"></script>
</svelte:head>

{ #if ready }
    <Map></Map>
{ /if }
```

`Map.svelte`

```html
<script>
    
    // Imports
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    // Globals
    let map;
    let container;

    // Load the map async
    onMount(async () => {
        map = new google.maps.Map(container, {
            zoom: 6,
            center: { lat: 0, lng: 0 },
        });
    });

    // This function has no access to the `map` variable created above!!
    function recenterMap() {
        map.setCenter({lat: 1, lng: 1});
    }
    
</script>

<div class="full-screen" bind:this={container}></div>
<button on:click="{recenterMap}"></button>
```

Running the above gives an error for trying to invoke the `setCenter` call on an object that does not exist. I've searched for how other frameworks (React, Vue) might handle this, but the solutions are specific to the frameworks and are not applicable here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: When are you getting this error? When the map is loaded and you click on the button? Or right away as the component is being rendered? Wrapping the `map.setCenter()` call inside an `if (map) { ... }` block might do the trick, it could be that somehow `recenterMap` is being evaluated before your component is actually mounted and `map` is properly initialized. Normally it's perfectly fine to declare variables at the global scope and initialize them inside `onMount`.

Comment: @ThomasHennes I was getting the error as the component was being rendered. 

Wrapping it in `if (map) { ... }` did the trick! Which means exactly that `recenterMap` was being evaluated _before_ map is mounted and initialized.

The above is a simplified version of my code... I think the real issue was the button click in my full code is actually a reactive declaration based on another component.

Thank you for the help!